# Why is the speed of incrementation doubling when the function is re-triggered twice?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand what is causing the speed movement of the UFO image to increase once the function has been re-triggered.

```js
var timer = null;
var el = null;
var stop = true;
var restart = false;
var stopforward = true;
var secondadd = false;

function moveit() {
  if (parseInt(el.style.left) > screen.width - 100) {
    stopforward = false;
  }
  if (stop) {
    if (stopforward) {
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px";
    }
  }

  timer = setTimeout(moveit, 25);

  if (stopforward == false) {
    if (stop) {
      if (parseInt(el.style.left) == 0) {
        stopforward = true;
      }
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) - 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px"
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  el = document.getElementById("img1");
  el.style.left = "0px";
  moveit();
  startstop();
}

function secondstart() {
  if (restart == true) {
    stop = true;
    moveit();
    restart = false;
  }
}

function startstop() {
  document.getElementById("start").removeEventListener("click", start, false);
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", secondstart, false);

}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start, false);
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
  stop = false;
  restart = true;
}
```

```css
#range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/e/2/7e2d7bea4ac21388c4a96e1371f375c4ce00094b.jpg);
  cursor: crosshair;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#start,
#stop {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="range">
  <div id="score"></div>
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/779-7799339_unidentified-flying-object-saucer-cartoon-ufo-png.png">
</div>


<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

Sorry if it looks a bit too convoluted. There really is no other way to actually show you what happens.

When you first click `start`, the ufo moves at a certain speed. When you click `stop`, and then `start` again, the speed doubles. This happens for two reasons. One is because when you click `start` the second time, you re-trigger the `moveit` function. The second is because the `setTimeout` method that re-triggers the `moveit` function is never disabled even when `stop` is clicked, because it is outside the `if` condition. This results in the function being triggered twice. I can see why that would lead to one iteration being doubled in speed, but why does it remain double?

**Note**, please don't give me any advice on how to "fix it". I know how to fix it. This isn't my question. This is purely a curiosity based question. I just want to understand why does the speed increase. What makes it increase.

**Note2**, you should view it on full screen.

Comment: BTW, if you want to do run a function periodically, `setInterval()` is the usual function, rather than repeatedly calling `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `moveIt()` method calls itself *recursively*. Once this process is started, it is never ending, as from within itself, the `stop` condition is trapped and the `moveIt` function is then set to behave accordingly (not moving the UFO, every 25ms).

However, in this instance, the `moveIt` function will keep being called. When you press start again, you invoke `secondstart()`, which will call `moveIt()` again, starting another timeout, and setting the `stop` variable so that the UFO moves.

The previously active timeout will now respond to this change in condition too, as `setTimeout` acts asynchronously. So now there will be two asyncrhonous instances of `moveIt()`, and if you repeat this operation there will be three, four and so on... All performing the same actions, which being CSS-based, will make your UFO move coherently, as its movement are calculated out of its instantaneous position.

I am still going to spill my two cents on what could be the quickest fix, because its **fun**... and might help others! So you probably guessed that already, but we need to find a way to get rid of that timeout, that you have wisely identified through the global variable `timer`.

You could then use the `clearTimeout()` method to perform `clearTimeout(timer)` within the `secondstart()` function. This way you clear the earlier timeout before starting a new one by invoking the `moveIt()` function again. Else... simply remove the second `moveIt()` call in the `secondstart()` function, as it is being executed already, and varying the `stop` variable will be enough to trigger a restart... with no adverse consequences!

Obviously, this will keep the `moveIt()` function being called continously even when the UFO is stopped, which maybe isn't super efficient.

```js
var timer = null;
var el = null;
var stop = true;
var restart = false;
var stopforward = true;
var secondadd = false;

function moveit() {
  if (parseInt(el.style.left) > screen.width - 100) {
    stopforward = false;
  }
  if (stop) {
    if (stopforward) {
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px";
    }
  }

  timer = setTimeout(moveit, 25);

  if (stopforward == false) {
    if (stop) {
      if (parseInt(el.style.left) == 0) {
        stopforward = true;
      }
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) - 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px"
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  el = document.getElementById("img1");
  el.style.left = "0px";
  moveit();
  startstop();
}

function secondstart() {
  if (restart == true) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    stop = true;
    moveit();
    restart = false;
  }
}

function startstop() {
  document.getElementById("start").removeEventListener("click", start, false);
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", secondstart, false);

}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start, false);
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
  stop = false;
  restart = true;
}
```

```css
#range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/e/2/7e2d7bea4ac21388c4a96e1371f375c4ce00094b.jpg);
  cursor: crosshair;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#start,
#stop {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="range">
  <div id="score"></div>
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/779-7799339_unidentified-flying-object-saucer-cartoon-ufo-png.png">
</div>


<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but when I tested that scenario, I ended up dismissing it, because when I put a second setTimeout right below the first one, the speed increases tremendously more, it doesn't just double. You're right that once the function it triggered the second time, the setTimeout is set again, and will thus forward keep getting re-triggered, but should that then increase the speed much more like it does when you just put a second setTimeout right beneath the first one?

Comment: By the way, to fix it, I just used the simplest solution, which is what you mentioned, just remove the `moveit()` from the second `start` button, so when you click the `start` again, you don't re-trigger the function, but just re-enable the `stop` condition.

Comment: But keep in mind that if if is this `timer = setTimeout(moveit, 25);` statement that you are talking about, if you have doubled it then it is totally normal that the speed is going out of control and not only doubling, because then the amount of timeouts is actually getting doubled everytime you call the `moveIt` function.

Comment: It is like **Mitosis** in biology... The cells split themselves, which then split themselves... and so on! `moveIt` would in that case be duplicating itself everytime it gets called. A more accurate attempt would to try duplicating the `moveIt()` function itself in the `secondstart()`. For every one that your add, you will be able to see how your speed gradually increases both for as many you add and for as many times you click on the STOP button and START again. So it's definitely the `setTimeouts` in this case which were doing the thing

Comment: So, when I put a second `timer = setTimeout(moveit, 25);` below the first one, now for each iteration, both are triggered.. but .. again, shouldn't then the speed be just double, like it is when I click the `start` button a second time? Sorry It's just a bit hard to visualize this. It's confusing.

Comment: No worries, it is totally fine. We are all here to learn, and it's great that you want to deep dive in even the smallest of the issues. The setTimeout within the `moveIt` function basically calls itself. If you double it, that basically means: (after 25 milliseconds, run me again, but twice). So every time you run moveIt, it will actually call itself again twice, after 25 ms. The first time it will duplicate, then these two copies we have created will **as well** double themselves after 25ms, as they will all act independently. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: It might sound silly but really look at this biology [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdKvdURrtDs), because this is exactly what's happening!

Comment: But why do they keep multiplying? When it's just one `timeout`, it basically means that, it re-triggers the function after 25 ms, then it reads the `timeout`, and re-triggers the function again after 25 ms. So, it's a self-triggering loop. Where is the multiplying? When you add a second `timeout` below the first, shouldn't that mean, the first `timeout` re-triggers the function, then the second `timeout` re-triggers it again, so the function is triggered twice, then again, both re-trigger it twice, and then again.. thus each time 6px become 12px. Where is the multiplying happening?

Comment: Remember that the setTimeout are not synchronous. They will be set and then the code execution will continue on, it won't just wait for the timeout to expire.  Aside that, do you agree that with two timeouts, MoveIt calls for MoveIt twice? If that is that case, after we call moveit once, we have two MoveIt(s)... And these are completely indipendent from each other, so when you run them, BOTH will call the setTimeout1 and setTimeout2.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4PYZ.jpg) picture. It should help you understand it...

Comment: I feel so stupid for not understanding this, but I feel like I do now. The picture did help. So in the second iteration, now we have 2 `moveit` being triggered, and each of them trigger the two `timeouts` again, resulting in 4 `moveits` being triggered, and so forth, for each iteration it keeps multiplying. I kind of understand it now, even though it isn't easy to visualize it. If you don't mind, I have another question. Why is it that, if you replace `setTimeout` for `setInterval` and set it to 1 sec for example, again, it keeps multiplying slowly until it gets to crazy speed? Why?

Comment: Even just one `setInterval` slowly multiplies until it gets to crazy speed. Where is the multiplying coming from? I thought It just re-triggers the function after 1sec. Why is it getting multiplied?

Comment: Don't worry. You are not stupid at all. This isn't so easy after all... and you're getting it now nonetheless, so that's great! The thing about setInterval(), is that, differently from setTimeout(), it calls for a function **every** x ms, and not just once after x ms like setTimeout()... so each time moveIt() gets called, a new instructions to recall moveIt **every** 25ms is issued.

Comment: So, with `setTimeout`, when the timeout is read, it triggers the function after 25ms, then when it's read again, it triggers it again and so on. But with `setInterval`, when it's read, it starts triggering the function every 1 second, when it's re-triggered, `setInterval` is read again, and it starts to re-trigger the function again after 1 second. So, now we have 2 `setIntervals` that keep re-triggering the function each second, and this multiplies with each triggering, and this is why the speed exponentially increases?

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. You've really helped me a lot to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

> please don't give me any advice on how to "fix it". I know how to fix it. This isn't my question.

OK.

> This is purely a curiosity based question. I just want to understand why does the speed increase. What makes it increase.

So we see that when `moveIt` is called it will *always* reschedule itself to be run again, using `setTimeout`. This means that once you call it, you have started an infinite sequence of calls, each separated by 25ms.

When the Start button is clicked, `moveIt` gets called. So far so good. It's doing what it should do. The Stop button works fine too. `moveIt` keeps continuing its repeated calls, but the `stop` variable now prevents it from making any changes.

The user clicks the Start button again. Now things go wrong: `moveIt` gets called again. So now we have *two* self-propagating sequences of `moveIt` calls. You can see how that doubles the speed of the changes.

In short, make sure you only call `moveIt` once, and let `setTimeout` do the rest. Don't call `moveIt` explicitly again.

### Comments

You write in comments:

> I thought about that, but when I tested that scenario, I ended up dismissing it.

Then I think you did not test it correctly. So now I will provide the fix:

In the function `secondstart` remove the call to `moveIt`:

```
function secondstart() {
  if (restart == true) {
    stop = true;
    // moveit(); // <------- remove!
    restart = false;
  }
}
```

Below the version with that correction so you can run it -- I didn't change anything else:

```js
var timer = null;
var el = null;
var stop = true;
var restart = false;
var stopforward = true;
var secondadd = false;

function moveit() {
  if (parseInt(el.style.left) > screen.width - 100) {
    stopforward = false;
  }
  if (stop) {
    if (stopforward) {
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px";
    }
  }

  timer = setTimeout(moveit, 25);

  if (stopforward == false) {
    if (stop) {
      if (parseInt(el.style.left) == 0) {
        stopforward = true;
      }
      el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) - 6 + "px";
      el.style.top = 100 + (80 * Math.sin(parseInt(el.style.left) / 50)) + "px"
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  el = document.getElementById("img1");
  el.style.left = "0px";
  moveit();
  startstop();
}

function secondstart() {
  if (restart == true) {
    stop = true;
    // moveit(); // <---- removed!
    restart = false;
  }
}

function startstop() {
  document.getElementById("start").removeEventListener("click", start, false);
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", secondstart, false);

}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start, false);
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {
  stop = false;
  restart = true;
}
```

```css
#range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/e/2/7e2d7bea4ac21388c4a96e1371f375c4ce00094b.jpg);
  cursor: crosshair;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#start,
#stop {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="range">
  <div id="score"></div>
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/779-7799339_unidentified-flying-object-saucer-cartoon-ufo-png.png">
</div>


<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but when I tested that scenario, I ended up dismissing it, because when I put a second `setTimeout` right below the first one, the speed increases tremendously more, it doesn't just double. You're right that once the function it triggered the second time, the `setTimeout` is set again, and will thus forward keep getting re-triggered, but should that then increase the speed much more like it does when you just put a second `setTimeout` right beneath the first one?

Comment: Well the effect is certainly different. If you call `setTimeout` twice, then you already have the double speed at the first click of the button. But why would you test like that? Just make sure you only call `moveIt` once explicitly, and never again. And that speed problem will be solved. I didn't post the code, since you wrote explicitly that you didn't want to have the fix, but now I think I should because you doubt my analysis is correct...

Comment: Added the fix to my answer.

Comment: I don't doubt your analysis is correct. You already told me something I hadn't considered before, but I am just curious, why when I just put a second `setTimeout` below the first, the speed is not doubled, but much much faster. Shouldn't the same thing then happen once the `start` is clicked the second time? Why is there a difference?

Comment: By the way, yes, I know that the way to fix it is by just removing the `moveit` from the second time the `start` is clicked. I am just trying to understand what is happening. I hate ignoring issues even when irrelevant.

Comment: Well, if you add a second `setTimeout(moveIt, 25)`, then *each* subsequent scheduled call will produce 2 timers again, and so you get from 1 to 2 to 4 to 8 to 16 ... chains of calls. So that is exponential growth.